# Tether materials considerations for sky hook with jet engine

Tags: design-alternative, skyhook

Suppose a skyhook was deployed with orbital dynamics mechanics such that when its hook side (opposite the counterweight) entered the atmosphere, it was nearly stationary with respect to local air average currents (similar to the tire of a moving car experiencing static friction with the road). Suppose further that the hook side has both a wing and a jet engine to perform orbital course corrections using the atmosphere both as oxidant and as something to push around. For the sake of argument, assume that on "odd" rotations, the skyhook catches and then releases a payload, and on "even" rotations, the jet engine engages and the wings are trimmed to re-acquire the lost kinetic energy from the previous cycle. How much would the materials considerations change for the tether?

Comment: I think an issue with your idea is that the tether would have to go so low in order for the air to be thick enough for the jet engines, that the velocity gained is not nearly as big as the velocity lost due to air resistance. Maybe you are thinking of a non air breathing engine, which is essentially a rocket engine. Then having the bottom of the skyhook entering the atmosphere is pointless. Also how are you planning to fuel the jet engine? And how deep into the atmosphere do you want the bottom of the skyhook to go?

Comment: @TheRocketfan If the hook is moving at about the same speed as the local air currents, the loss due to friction will be fairly small. Given that "target" air speed for the tether is 0, after a launch, the air should actually pull the tether forward (obviously, at the cost of rotational velocity - which is why there's a jet). I see nothing terribly difficult with each payload bringing fuel for the tether. As for the type of air-breathing engine, I believe jets work well enough, but if a prop was better at intended speeds...

Comment: You want the skyhook to be moving at 0 m/s at the bottom and yes, that is possible, but you also need to get the hook down, meaning that there still will be air resistance. Imagine being on a wheel of a car on the freeway. When you are at the bottom, you are moving with 0 m/s relative to the ground, but you will accelerate pretty quickly upwards. So even if you are at the bottom of the skyhook, during the descent and ascent stage, there will be air resistance and the velocity will build up very quickly. So yes, air resistance is a problem and cannot be ignored.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ion/electric engines are far more efficient in vacuum compared to conventional jet engines in-atmosphere. Because of this, I think it would be smarter to "reload" the energy in the system outside of the atmosphere. Yes, the thrust is low, but you can run it almost continuously.

Comment: @Dragongeek What you say *may* be true, but that would mean a rocket to get to the hook, whereas if the hook is in the upper atmosphere, a balloon will do the job.

Comment: @TheRocketfan Air resistance scales with velocity, but so does "lift" from the wing which, given the airfoil of a multi-billion-dollar project, should be at least 15x drag (20x might be more reasonable, but the range of speeds and air densities will call for compromises). I put lift in quotes because the direction of force may not be up. Such a tether would be capped in length by the requirement not to squish the cargo.

Comment: @user121330 It is hard to calculate numbers because you didn’t provide much detail. We do not know how high the skyhook is orbiting, how long the tether is, how deep into the atmosphere you want to have the rope etc. Also what I was trying to say is that if you want to have a skyhook low enough so that a jet engine could accelerate it, then you will indefinitely have intense airresistance even if the skyhook is travelling at 0m/s at the bottom because the skyhook still has its momentum, meaning that it will gain its velocity very quickly.

Comment: @user121330 even if you have almost no airresistance, when you increase the velocity at the end of the rope, you will increase its momentum, not its orbital velocity.

Comment: @TheRocketfan I receive notices by virtue of the fact that it's my question - the '@s' are extraneous. BTW, you are correct - the problem is somewhat under-defined. I will investigate the TRL to find the longest available tether, then work my way backwards to put numbers to the thing - of course, if the wing causes more tensile strain on the tether than the payload, the tether would necessarily be shorter. My hope, of course, was that somebody had already built models to investigate skyhooks and that such calculations would be trivial for them.

Comment: About the "@". I am so used to saying @… that I didn’t even think twice about it. If you prefer that I didn’t say @ then no problem . Just let me know

Comment: You should submit an abstract to the ISDC if you have done some modeling work to validate it. I think it may be an original idea.